# Custom managers in a Many-to-Many relation for usual filters

Tags: django, django-orm, django-managers

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name="author")

    def get_tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(tagged_proposals=self.id) 

class Tag(models.Model):
    tagged_proposals = models.ManyToManyField(Proposal)
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
```

I need to list the proposal's tags on a certain template so I would write `{% for tag in proposal.get_tags %}` and it works perfectly.

Now I read about Managers and it seems a good move to convert my `get_tags` into a Manager. I tried the following but it didn't output a thing. What am I doing wrong? Does it make sense to turn it a Manager in the first place?

```
class ProposalsTagsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
                proposal_id = how-do-i-get-the-proposal-id???
        return Tag.objects.filter(tagged_proposals=proposal_id)
```

usage: `{% for tag in p.tags.all %}` output: nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom function for this.

When a table is being referenced with a ManyToManyField you get a method called MODEL_set to get a queryset of that model.

So in your case you can reference all your tags like this:

```
proposal = Proposal.objects.get(pk=1)
tags = proposal.tag_set.all() # You can also use filter here
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know about that! One of the main problems I'm having with Django is the lack of throughout documentation (for beginners). There are a lot of Django's features that are hard to discover for a Django beginner.